# How can I generate and send a PDF file to the browser from a lambda function?

Tags: node.js, pdf, aws-lambda, netlify

I’m having trouble writing a serverless lambda function (through Netlify Functions) to convert some dynamic html into a pdf, and then send that pdf file on in response to the request.

I'm using the [`html-pdf` NPM module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf) for the actual conversion.

I’m able to generate the file fine, but when I try to send that file back, I am getting errors like `Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end`  or `[ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`.

I feel like it could be:

- me not knowing how to send a file buffer/stream?
- not knowing how to make the function wait until the conversion is
  complete before returning

full code:

```
const generateHtml = require("./generateHtml")
const pdf = require("html-pdf")

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    try {
        let shortlist = JSON.parse(event.body)

        pdf.create(generateHtml(shortlist), {
            format: "Letter",
            orientation: "portrait",
            border: "1in"
        }).toBuffer((err, buffer) => {
            console.log("callback triggered")
            return {
                statusCode: 200,
                headers: {
                    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
                    "Content-Type": "application/pdf",
                },
                body: buffer.toString()
            }
        })
    } catch(err) {
        return {
            statusCode: 500,
            body: err.toString()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know I am late to this. But did you find the problem or the solution to this?

Comment: not really. the fairest answer i could find is "serverless is still new and some things are just difficult". i did it in a more normal node app instead, works great!

when i came to do a similar feature again more recently, i took a slightly different tactic:

i served a "printable version" with different css, and used browser javascript to trigger the print dialog in the browser. that might be a better solution for you too, depending on your use case.

Comment: That is a good way to implement it. I've used that tactic before, but my scenario this time is that the client wants to pdf to be emailed to them. I might need to use a different FAAS hosting.